# Can we get the Coverity report specific to only one issue like URL Manipulation Error?

Tags: rest, static-analysis, coverity

I am using cov-capture, and cov-analyze to get the reports in my VM. Can anyone help in getting the command to run the cov-analyze only for getting specific errors? Example: There are various XML files created and analysis takes time to run. So to save time If we can get only a single report for a single issue like URL Manipulation or Encryption Error.
Note:  Tool Used in Synopsys with REST API code in python and flask.

Answer (score 1):

To run the analysis with only a single checker enabled, use the `--disable-default` and `--enable` options like this:

```
$ cov-analyze --disable-default --enable CHECKER_NAME ...
```

`CHECKER_NAME` is the all-caps, identifier-like name of the checker that reports issues of a certain type.  For URL Manipulation, the checker is called `PATH_MANIPULATION`.  The Checker Reference lists all of the checker names.

However, be aware that doing this repeatedly for each checker will take significantly longer than simply running all desired checkers at once because there is substantial overhead involved in simply reading the program into memory for analysis.

If your goal is faster analysis turnaround for changes you are making during development before check-in or push, you may want to look into using the `cov-run-desktop` command, which is meant for that use case.